Unit of work is being used but im not understanding where to put the commit in the repository class or in controller?
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> EmployeeEdit(EmployeeViewModel model)
{
    var emp = await _unitOfWork.Employee.FindById(model.EmployeeId);
    if (emp == null)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, error = "Employee not found." });
    }  
    if(model.ProfilePictureImg.Length > 0)
    {
        var docResponse = _unitOfWork.DocumentImage.UploadFile(model.ProfilePictureImg,     _appSettings.DocumentImagePath);
        model.ProfilePicture = docResponse.VirtualPath;
    }
    var updateResult = await _unitOfWork.Employee.UpdateEmployee(model);
    if(updateResult == true)
    {
        await _unitOfWork.Commit();

    }
    return Json(new { success = updateResult });
}

`in the above code where should i used the commit() in the UpdateEmployee or in the controller as above and should i need to check the updateResult before commiting or i have to do something for the unit of work class to check itself?
i wana know what is the standard way to do it in the unit of work?`

I think it should be out of UpdateEmployee, because sometimes you will want to update more than one entity object in one Commit.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It looks like you are trying to better design your code. I would start with solid principles. For you the key here is the single responsibility principle. Unit of work is responsible to commit the changes but the responsibility of when the changes should be commited should go to some business logic layer. In your case it is the api method EmployeeEdit, which is maybe not perfect, but still ok. I would create an EmployeeProvider (check the Provider Pattern), move your code there and use it in your api controller. Because the api controller is too specific about data transfer stuff and not the business logic.
